# Symfony2 sylius RbacBundle creating new user with admin role

Tags: symfony, rbac, sylius

I installed rbacBundle and is working fine, but...

I've already create an administrator roled user, now I want to create a new one without drop the first, and I get this error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO sylius_user_role (user_id, role_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [5, 4]:

 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
 '4' for key 'UNIQ_1DA28211D60322AC'
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because for default both join columns on the join table are set to unique, so you should change it like this:

```
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)},
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)}
```

Afer that update your scheme and that's it. Let me know if it works.